# Python syntax error while assigning variable

Tags: python

I am new to python I am trying to assign variable it says systax error

```
protocol = input.readLine()
connectUrlHttp='http'
connectUrlHttps='https'


if protocol== "t3s":
 connectUrl=connectUrlHttps
elif protocol== "iiops":
  connectUrl=connectUrlHttps
else:
connectUrl=connectUrlHttp


  sca_deployComposite(connectUrl"://"+host+":"+port,emdroot+"/"+compositeLoc,owrite,user, password,default)
```

I am facing below error

```
(no code object) at line 0
  File "/scratch/agentHome/sdappaji2/core/12.1.0.3.0/EMStage/PAF/DeployCompositesDP1367835748253/deploycompositesscripts/deployComposites.py", line 36
    connectUrl=connectUrlHttp
```

Please guide me and give some pointers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, [**indentation**](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) levels are significant:

> Use 4 spaces per indentation level.

*--[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)*

Your code should probably look like this:

```
protocol = input.readLine()
connectUrlHttp = 'http'
connectUrlHttps = 'https'

if protocol == "t3s":
    connectUrl = connectUrlHttps
elif protocol == "iiops":
    connectUrl = connectUrlHttps
else:
    connectUrl = connectUrlHttp

# Note the `+` after `connectUrl` on the next line:
sca_deployComposite(connectUrl + "://" + host + ":" + port, emdroot + "/" +
                    compositeLoc, owrite, user, password, default)
```

Answer (score 1):

The actual syntax error is here:

```
sca_deployComposite(connectUrl"://"+host+":"+port,emdroot+"/"+compositeLoc,owrite,user, password,default)
                            ^^^
```

You probably missed a `+` there.

The indentation is also wrong after the `else`, as Ashwini points out.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not properly indented after `else:`

```
if protocol== "t3s":
 connectUrl=connectUrlHttps
elif protocol== "iiops":
  connectUrl=connectUrlHttps
else:
    connectUrl=connectUrlHttp

sca_deployComposite(connectUrl+"://"+host+":"+port,emdroot+"/"+compositeLoc,owrite,user, password,default)
```

Plus you were missing a `+` after `sca_deployComposite(connectUrl`.